# How to get sum of order detail in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have to tables to save orders and order_details

**orders**

```
id
name
```

**order_details**

```
id
name
quantity
price
order_id
```

This is how I get total price

**Transaction.php**

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Detail');
}

public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->details()->sum(DB::raw('quantity * price));
}
```

Is there any way more elegant?

Comment: You could do a `reduce` operation on `$this->details()->get()`, but that would end up being more lines of code without, i think, much more readability. But `reduce` is kind of fun.